Hilt with ksp instead of kapt
how to use hilt with ksp instead of kapt seems like i can't figure it out
please let me know what dependencies should i add and how should i add them
dependencies i added:
//hilt
    val hiltVersion = "2.51"  
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hiltVersion")

plugins:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17"
}

build gradle:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false
}

i tried different hilt versions like 2.48.1
different kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion like 1.5.8
nothing seems to work i've got multiple different errors don't know what i'm doing neither do i know what i'm doing wrong

When using kotlin, ksp and compose you have to keep in mind to use versions that are compatible with each other, otherwise building the project will most likely fail.
Kotlin and KSP
Take a look at releases, ksp version always consist of two parts e.g. 1.9.23-1.0.20 where 1.9.23 is kotlin version and 1.0.20 is actual KSP version (i think).
Kotlin and Compose
List of compatible versions can be found in Android docs.
Your case
Since you are using kotlin 1.9.0 you should use KSP 1.9.0-1.0.13 and kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.5.2. For the dagger it should word fine for version 2.48 and above based on this, so version 2.51 is fine.

kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion is no longer relevant for projects using Kotlin 2.x, Compose Kotlin Compiler is now versioned in step with Kotlin since its move from Google over to JetBrains.

At your project level build.gradle add below plugins:
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.23"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.23-1.0.20"
}

And in build.gradle(app), add this plugin:
plugins {
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

Dependencies:
// Hilt
val hilt = "2.50"
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt")
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt")


Make sure you have latest and stable compose version:
In app's build.gradle

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
}


Miroslav Hybler's answer worked for me but the thing that attracted my attention to your answer is why would i add
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
instead of
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

No, i didn't asked to remove org.jetbrains.kotlin.android, it should be there!!. I suggested to add org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm as extra plugin because if you add room_dependency in future in project than it will be required.

Kotlin Version = 2.0.10
build.gradle (Project) > plugins
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.0.10-1.0.24" apply false

build.gradle (Module) > (1) plugins
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
id("com.google.devtools.ksp")

(2) dependencies
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.51.1")

Links
Dependency injection with Hilt
Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map
Releases-google/ksp

If you are using KSP you need to use this libraries
ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.50")

